# Frobenius splitting from viewpoint of commutative algebra

Tags: reference-request, commutative-algebra

First I define two terms:
Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity, let char$R$ = $p$, let $F:R\rightarrow R$ be the Frobenius ring homomorphism. This makes $R$ into an $R$-module with respect to the action $rs := F(r)s=r^p s.$ We say that $R$ is *F-split* if there exists $G:R\rightarrow R$ such that $G\circ F = Id.$ $R$ is called *F-pure* if $F\otimes Id_E:R\otimes E\rightarrow R\otimes E$ is injective for all $R$-modules $E$.

I want to learn about F-Splitting and F-purity for my commutative algebra presentation. However, I have searched the internet and everywhere they start the discussion with schemes, ideal sheaves etc. I want to avoid schemes and stuff and focus solely on commutative algebra aspect. Can somebody suggest good reference for these things, where the discussion is purely in terms of commutative algebra and not Algebraic Geometry? I need it urgently!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you look for tight closure?

Comment: A recent preprint of Smith and Zhang: http://arxiv.org/abs/1409.1169

Comment: Cross-posted: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/181134/f-splitting-and-f-purity-from-commutative-algebra-viewpoint